# Pass parameters from a function to another function where parameters have the same name in Python

Tags: python, naming-conventions

Let's say I have a parameter in a function that I want to pass to another function, and both parameter are named the same (because they represent the same logical element) - How do I handle this nicely?

```
def myFunc1(df):
   myFunc2(df=df)

def myFunc2(someArg=None, df=None):
   # Do sth.
```

Since every now and then, I ran into some problems caused by the ambiguity of `df=df`, my current approach is mainly to rename the parameters in the different methods, e.g. so that in one method it is called `_df` and in the other one `df`. 
However, I don't think this is a nice way to deal with this. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: `df=df` says the key argument `df` is the local variable called `df`. Where is the problem ?

Comment: what ambiguity?

Comment: Yes, this idiom is actually quite common, like `key=key` and `reverse=reverse` used in the CPython code test suite here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/test/test_heapq.py#L166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my current approach is mainly to rename the parameters in the different methods, e.g. so that in one method it is called _df and in the other one df.

Don't. This is even worse.

---

I agree with people saying there is no apparent ambiguity with your specified case. But if your goal is to respect whatever imposed code design, here is one thing you could do.

You state in your question that parameters are named the same *because they represent the same logical element*. The thing is, your function don't or at least I hope they don't.

So one thing you could do is prefix your `df` variable with what logic is applied internally in the function.

Ex.

```
def myFunc1(df):
    #sort df here
    myFunc2(sorted_df=df)

def myFunc2(someArg=None, sorted_df=None):
```

Note that this is a dummy example to show a possible solution. You can adapt it to your needs.

Also, if you literally only work with the initial `df` instance then if you correctly choose your functions name, no ambiguity will ever arise. Following the same above logic,

```
def myFunc1(df):
    sort_df(df=df)

def sort_df(someArg=None, sorted_df=None):
```

To me, this seems totally fine.

I think that your specific case brings some sort of ambiguity because your function are obviously wrongly named (probably for example purpose, but still.)